# Почему не выводится фотография в дочернем окне tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Вот мой код:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    
    
def Help():
    def Destroy():
        window.destroy()   

    window=tk.Tk()
    window.title("Новое окно")
    window.geometry("300x180")
    
    label = ttk.Label(window, text="Высота", foreground='black',
                       font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="c") 

    submit = Button(window, text='Cancel',
                     command=Destroy).place(relx=0.8, rely=0.8, anchor="c", width=70, height=30) 

    ph=Image.open('pop.png')
    ph=ph.resize((300,300), Image.LANCZOS)
    ph=ImageTk.PhotoImage(ph)
    ph=Label(window, image=ph)
    ph.image=ph
    ph.place(x=10, y=10)


def OK():
    p = entry1.get()
    print(p)
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    entry2.insert(0,p)


def Cancel():
    root.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title("Параметры стандартной атмосферы")
root.geometry("700x400")
root.resizable(False, False)

label1 = ttk.Label(text="Высота", foreground='black',
                   font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.1, anchor="c")
label2 = ttk.Label(text="Поле ввода высоты", foreground='black',
                   font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2, anchor="c")
label3 = ttk.Label(text="Давление", foreground='black',
                   font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.2, rely=0.6, anchor="c")
label4 = ttk.Label(text="Плотность", foreground='black',
                   font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.4, rely=0.6, anchor="c")
label5 = ttk.Label(text="Температура", foreground='black',
                   font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.6, anchor="c")
label6 = ttk.Label(text="Скорость звука", foreground='black',
                   font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.8, rely=0.6, anchor="c")

entry1 = ttk.Entry()
entry1.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.1, anchor="c")
entry2 = ttk.Entry()
entry2.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2, anchor="c")
entry3 = ttk.Entry().place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5, anchor="c")
entry4 = ttk.Entry().place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5, anchor="c")
entry5 = ttk.Entry().place(relx=0.6, rely=0.5, anchor="c")
entry6 = ttk.Entry().place(relx=0.8, rely=0.5, anchor="c")

submit1 = Button(root, text='Cancel',
                 command=Cancel).place(relx=0.2, rely=0.8, anchor="c", width=70, height=30)
submit2 = Button(root, text='Help',
                 command=Help).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor="c", width=70, height=30)
submit3 = Button(root, text='OK',
                 command=OK).place(relx=0.7, rely=0.8, anchor="c", width=70, height=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> image «pyimage1» doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, как вы создаете и воспроизводите метку изображения в дочернем окне. Вам нужно убедиться, что объект "Photo Image" не уничтожен сборщиком мусора, что может произойти, когда он выходит за пределы области видимости.

Вот измененная функция `Help`, которая должна устранить проблему:

```python
def Help():
    def Destroy():
        window.destroy()

    window = Toplevel(root)
    window.title("Новое окно")
    window.geometry("300x300")

    label = ttk.Label(window, text="Высота", foreground='black',
                      font='Arial 10').place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="c")

    ph = Image.open('pop.png')
    ph = ph.resize((200, 200), Image.LANCZOS)
    ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ph)
    ph_label = Label(window, image=ph)
    ph_label.image = ph  # сохранение ссылки на изображение
    ph_label.place(x=50, y=50)

    submit = Button(window, text='Cancel',
                    command=Destroy).place(relx=0.8, rely=0.8, anchor="c", width=70, height=30)
```

Что изменилось:

1. Мы создаем дочернее окно, используя верхний уровень вместо Tk (TopLevel);
2. Мы создаем объект "PhotoImage" и метку изображения `ph_label` отдельно;
3. Мы сохраняем ссылку на изображение, используя `ph_label.image = photo`;
4. Мы помещаем метку изображения в окно, используя `ph_label.place()`.

Это должно предотвратить уничтожение объекта "PhotoImage" и позволить отображаться изображению в дочернем окне. При необходимости можете вернуть значения размера окна, ресайза и расположения изображения обратно на свои.

Comment: Понял, ошибки исправил, заработало. Спасибо!